# Как получить объект из списка в шаблоне django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-model

Есть список, который передается в шаблон. Например:

```
d = ['Первая категория', 'Вторая категория', 'Третья категория', 'Четвертая категория', 'Пятая категория']
```

В шаблоне HTML

```
{{ d.0 }} {{ d.2 }} {{ d.4 }}
```

Все выводится как нужно, но если мне нужно динамически передавать индекс списка

Например, есть модель

```
class Mod(models.Model):
name = models.TextField(
verbose_name='Название'
    )
cat = models.IntegerField(
    verbose_name='Номер категории'
)
```

В шаблоне

```
{% for el in Mod %}
...
{{ d.el.cat }}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Это не работает и по идее не должно, но как тогда вывести, если не использовать числовые значения

Модель и список даны чисто для примера, поэтому о смысле такой операции задумываться не стоит

Comment: Попробуйте так: `d|slice:el.cat`

Comment: Теперь он выводит значение, но не одно а все с 1 по заданное

Answer (score 0):

Передача индекса объекта в шаблон осуществляется через url

```
path('index/<int:pk>/', views.index)
```

При этом ваша функция index должна принимать соответствующий параметр и затем передавать в шаблон.

Comment: Что-то как-то совсем мимо вопроса

Comment: задайте вопрос конкретней

Comment: Вопрос был не в том. С передачей в шаблон данных нет. Есть вопрос с их обработкой внутри шаблона